# Wi-Fi auto-connection to public wifi and pass captive portal automatically

Tags: android

Every time when mobile devices connect to a public wifi, a captive portal pops out, either username and password are required or acceptances of terms. Here is one of functions of my app which need to connect to wifi, for convenience, when a captive portal show up, I would like the an Activity click the checkbox,or the button, and log in the Wifi.
My thought is to read the content loaded on a webview in the activity, and then search the checkbox or accept Buttons to change the status.
Is that even possible?

Comment: this depends if you can handle the captive portal condition to launch your app. Which would generally just launch a browser. But this changed in L.

Comment: So here is my understanding: The status of widget on the web is irrelevant to this function. The only way to make it happen is to communicate with router side. BUT still one question to go, HOW could the router detect the status of checkbox or buttons, if we could intercept and make the router believe we have press the button, this would work. Is that even possible?

Comment: I have already solve the problem and test on one of the public wifi which only requests the acceptance of terms. It could set the button onClick once the webview is redirect to the captive portal....